# HTML tag input text line-height not working

Tags: html, css

I have this :

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="#" style="margin-left:130px;">

    <input type="text" style="color:black;height:150px;width:325px;line-height: normal !important;display:block;" >

</form>
```

very simple.
The text is in the mdll if the input , and i want the text will apear on top.

line-height: normal !important; not working.

Its working good at IE , but in firefox and chrome the text apears in the middle of the input.

What can i do ?

Comment: The `line-height` property specifies the distance between baselines of text. It is not expected to affect vertical positioning. It seems that your real problem was the attempt to use a single-line input control for multi-line input, but neither the question title nor the question body says this.

Comment: `line-height`, even with `!important`, will never work in Firefox: at the browser level, Firefox already defines explicit line-height with ~important... you will never be able to override this until one day they decide to not do this anymore. It's been a known thing for years. Look for other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want more space, use the `<textarea>` tag instead of the `<input type="text">` tag.
Use Internal or external css because it is a very bad idea to use css rules in internal for multiple same type tags.

```
Check it how to use it 
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
   textarea{
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0.857143rem;
    line-height: 1.71429;
    padding: 0.714286rem;
    width: 325px;
    height:150px;
   }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="#" style="margin-left:130px;">

   <textarea id="comment" aria-required="true" rows="8" cols="45" name="comment"></textarea>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="input-lg"/>
```

css:

```
.input-lg {

height: 45px;

padding: 10px 16px;

font-size: 18px;

line-height: 1.33;

border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Not working either, the text is still in the middle look at my height is 150px .

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfncE/)



make css class using `<style type="text/css"> css code </style>`

Comment: Uday Hiwarale,its still not good and i using textarea tag already thanks.